# How to create REST endpoint service consume multipart using Spring 4.x?

Tags: spring, rest

I am trying to create a REST service that consumes the "multipart/form-data" with text and attachment objects. For files i can use "org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile", but how do i specify the service method for Text objects?

Below is the expected client call to service.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

create Rest endpoint by using this way

```
  public void sendEmail(@RequestParam String to,@RequestParam String from,@RequestParam String cc,@RequestParam String body, @RequestParam(required = false)MultipartFile[] file){
  }
```

or

create `pojo` class for strings

```
public class Email{
  private String from;
  private String to;
  private String cc;
  private String body;
 // getters and setters
}
 //email should be json string
 public void sendEmail(@RequestParam String email,@RequestParam(required = false) MultipartFile[] file){
   ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
   Email email_pojo=mapper.readValue(email,Email.class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create the controller as specified below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFiles", headers = ("content-type=multipart/*"), method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public AppDTO uploadFile(UploadFiles uploadFiles, HttpServletRequest request) {
```

Now create a pojo class for what ever things you need to submit along with a multipartfile member where the file will bind to. refer below code for pojo

```
class UploadFiles
{
private String cc;
private String to;
private String from;

private MultipartFile attachment;

//create getters and setters

}
```

MultipartFile here used is provided by spring

```
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
```

If you have more than one attachment you can use `MultipartFile[]` in POJO

Comment: I have created an Email object and referenced as @RequestParam in method and get following error. TTP Status 400 - Required Email parameter 'email' is not present

Comment: @user1541472  Why requestparam? If you want change that requestParam to `@ModelAttribute`